# PHP - errors with my loops

Tags: php, loops

I tried to push in array different values from multidimentionnal object array.

My object seems to be like that in `'Chapter'` :

```
 object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[5301]
  private 'snapshot' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity\Chapitre)[5335]
          private 'id' => int 1
          private 'titre' => string 'C01' (length=3)
          private 'Videos' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[5371]
              ...
      1 => 
        object(Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity\Chapitre)[5373]
          private 'id' => int 2
          private 'titre' => string 'C02' (length=3)
          private 'Videos' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[5374]
              ...
      2 => 
        object(Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity\Chapitre)[5376]
          private 'id' => int 3
          private 'titre' => string 'C03' (length=3)
          private 'Tutoriel' => 
          private 'Videos' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[5377]
              ...
```

and in `'Videos'`

```
0 => 
        object(Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity\Video)[5831]
          private 'id' => int 4
          private 'titre' => string 'qzesthbvs s hgqsd' (length=17)
          private 'prix' => int 0
          private 'level' => string 'hard' (length=8)
1 => 
        object(Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity\Video)[5831]
          private 'id' => int 4
          private 'titre' => string 'qzesthbvs s hgqsd' (length=17)
          private 'prix' => int 0
          private 'level' => string 'noob' (length=8)
```

Before to try in PHP I did this in Javascript :

```
var NIV = [0, 1, 2];
NIV[0] = [];
NIV[1] = [];
NIV[2] = [];
            $.each(e.tuto.Chapiter, function(idx, chapiter) {
                $.each(chapiter.Videos, function(idx, video) {
                    switch (video.level) {
                        case "noob":
                            NIV[0].push(video.level);
                            break;
                        case "medium":
                            NIV[1].push(video.level);
                            break;
                        case "hard":
                            NIV[2].push(video.level);
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
```

But now I need to do the same thing in PHP. I tried to do that but I'm not expert in PHP and I think I have a problem in my loops... How to select `'Level'` ?

I did that :

```
$NIV = [0, 1, 2];
    $NIV[0] = [];
    $NIV[1] = [];
    $NIV[2] = [];

    foreach ($chap as $section => $video) {
        foreach ($video as $niveau => $value) {
            switch ($value.niveau) {
                case "noob":
                    array_push($NIV[0], ($value.level));
                    break;
                case "medium":
                    array_push($NIV[1], ($value.level));
                    break;
                case "hard":
                    array_push($NIV[2], ($value.level));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

For information, here is the rest of my code to do a weighted average of all levels from all Videos:

```
    $nb_noob = sizeof($NIV[0]);
    $nb_medium = sizeof($NIV[1]);
    $nb_hard = sizeof($NIV[2]);

    $total_niv = $nb_noob + $nb_medium + $nb_hard ;

    $ratio_nb_noob  = $nb_noob / $total_niv;
    $ratio_nb_medium  = $nb_medium / $total_niv;
    $ratio_nb_hard = $nb_hard / $total_niv;

    $weighted_average= $ratio_nb_noob  * 1 + $ratio_nb_medium  * 2 + $ratio_nb_hard * 3;

    $weighted_average= round($weighted_average);
```

thanks !

Comment: This is javascript `switch ($value.niveau)` what you want is for php `switch ($value['niveau'])`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
$NIV    = [0, 1, 2];
$NIV[0] = 0;
$NIV[1] = 0;
$NIV[2] = 0;

foreach ($Chapter->snapshot as $section => $row) 
{
    foreach ($row->Videos as $niveau => $video) 
    {
        switch ($video->level) 
        {
            case "noob":
                $NIV[0]++;
                break;
            case "medium":
                $NIV[1]++;
                break;
            case "hard":
                $NIV[2]++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can access object index with `$video->level`

And now you doesnt need `size_of` function. Just get it with `$NIV[0]` that returns `count`

Comment: Hello ! It doesn't work but it's nearly the good result I think :) . I edit my post regarding the Object array... Is it change something ?

Comment: @Zagloo Before update the answer, what do you want to push index, video level? video id? So what contains `$NIV` array?

Comment: The finality of this code is to do a weighted average of all Video Levels. I put the rest of my code now. So I just need to push level of each video, count how many of each different level there are and do a weighted average

Comment: @Zagloo Updated answer with new `named variables` like `$Chapter->snapshot`. Sure this variables

Comment: I cant help you in this way. `always not working` Not working what? Do you get any errors? Did you dump it `var_dump($NIV);`

Comment: you're rigth sorry... when I do a var_dump($NIV); i get this : 
array (size=3)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 0
  2 => int 0

Comment: @Zagloo `echo $Chapter->snapshot[0]->id` and `echo $Chapter->snapshot[0]->Videos[0]->level` try these and tell me getting the values or not?

Comment: I found the solution :) Thanks for your help !! You show me the rigth way ;)

Comment: @Zagloo Congratulations! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :)

```
$NIV = [0, 1, 2];
    $NIV[0] = 0;
    $NIV[1] = 0;
    $NIV[2] = 0;

    foreach ($chapter as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value->getVideos() as $index => $val) {
            switch ($val->getLevel()) {
                case "noob":
                    $NIV[0] ++;
                    break;
                case "medium":
                    $NIV[1] ++;
                    break;
                case "hard":
                    $NIV[2] ++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    $total_niv = $NIV[0] + $NIV[1] + $NIV[2];

    $ratio_nb_noob = $NIV[0] / $total_niv;
    $ratio_nb_medium = $NIV[1] / $total_niv;
    $ratio_nb_hard = $NIV[2] / $total_niv;

    $weighted_average = $ratio_nb_noob * 1 + $ratio_nb_medium * 2 + $ratio_nb_hard * 3;
    $weighted_average = round($weighted_average );
```